# Ionic printer plugin not working on ios for external link

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, ionic2, ionic3

**I am trying to print external link into ionic app using ionic printer plugin**
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer/

```
 printticket(){
      let printurl = "http://www.gmail.com";

          let options: PrintOptions = {
              name: 'Waridi Events',
              duplex: true,
              landscape: false,
              grayscale: false
          };


           this.printer.print(printurl, options).then(onSuccess=>{
               console.log("Done =>" + onSuccess);
           }, onError=>{
             console.log("Error=>"+onError);
           });
  }
```

> **This is working on android but not working on ios. Please give me some better way to print.**
>
> **sometimes it is working**

[image]

> **And sometimes failed to load data**
>   [image]

Answer (score -1):

**Finally I got the solution using api call.**

**Before call the print call the api from the link and get the html codes and save all into a variable and print it.**